# MS Access - Edit linked table data in grid view

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

I have a query that links up a few tables to give a result set. I have this query in Access 2016 and have all the permissions set to update the data.

I can view the data in the grid view without any issues but I cannot edit the data like I would expect to if I did this through SQL Management Studio when I right click on a table and select the "Edit Top 200 Rows" option

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please share the query and table structure (indexes, the relevant fields).

Comment: See: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html) and [Allen Browne: Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) -- Also make sure that every linked table shows the correct **primary key** in table design.